# Three.js GPGPU Water Example (What is changing?)

Tags: javascript, three.js, gpgpu

Recently, I have been extensively exploring the source code for this Three.js example: [gpgpu / water](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpgpu_water.html).

I think that this example is super cool, and I was hoping to use the values of the water to affect certain things in other parts of my script (perhaps mapping one of the values to an oscillator's frequency).  However, I have not been able to find what is actually changing in the data.  Anyone can plainly see that some kind of data is changing.  If you show the wireframe, then you can see vertices and lines moving in 3D space.  Something is changing!  But I can't find what it is.

I'm pretty sure that the custom shader has a lot to do with me being unable to find anything.  Perhaps the values are hidden somewhere in GPU Land where I can't access them, but I have no idea.  I've even looked at values within the GPUComputationRenderer.js script that's used to help with this example, but EVERYTHING seems to be static.

Granted, I'm pretty new to 3D graphics in general, so all of my findings and assumptions may be wrong.  Either way, I just want someone to tell me where some kind of data is changing.

A huge thanks to anyone that can help me out with this!  At this point, I just want to regain my sanity.

Comment: I just implemented that example into a game I'm developing.  I believe the values you're lookin' for are in the "heightmapFragmentShader" code.  I realize this question is a few years old, but it had no answers so..

Comment: @M1ke Yeah I forgot I even asked this question, but thanks!